# Is there anyway to use IndexOf("blah") function with case insensitive in VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to maintain a VB.Net project created long time ago by using .NET Framework 1.1.

It uses IndexOf("blah") function. I want to use it without considering the case. I search lot and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364442/are-net-string-operations-case-sensitive) and [this](http://www.ezineasp.net/post/VB-Net-IndexOf-String-Function.aspx) solutions.

But the problem is in my Framework there is not StringComparison class. So how I get this class to my project. (I tried to add references) If it is not possible, is there anyway to do case insensitive search?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `is in my Framework there is not StringComparison class` which Framework you are using?

Comment: @Anuraj, the question states .NET 1.1, i.e. VB.NET 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dodgy version of case-insensitivity that some people still use, e.g.

```
Dim index As Integer = myString.ToLower().IndexOf(substring.ToLower())
```

Just note that that can have culture-related issues.